# How to test for dynamic URL parameters being defined in PHP?

Tags: php, url, parameters, fpdf, defined

I'm calling a `fpdf` file through an URL. For some calls I need to supply specific parameters, which are only used on specific calls. I cannot update all calls to the FPDF file, so I want to test inside the file, whether a URL parameter exists.

I'm trying like this:

```
<?php
 require('fpdf.php');
 ini_set('display_errors', 1);
 error_reporting(E_ALL);
 import_request_variables("GP", "rvar_");

 if (isset($rvar_store){
 ... set something
 }
```

So the URL parameter `store` will be passed on some php-calls, while there is no parameter on others.

The above doesn't work (I get a blank page).

**Question**:
How do I test for a URL parameter? I need to test if it is defined?

**EDIT:**
My url called will look like this:

```
 fpdf/item.php?iln="+ilns+"&sprache="+locale+"&bestellkeys="+bestellkeys;
```

or when I have my spec param:

```
  fpdf/bestellung.php?iln="+ilns+"&sprache="+locale+"&bestellkeys="+bestellkeys+"&store=true";
```

Comment: Url parameter, as in `?param=etc`?

Comment: oh. yes, I'm sorry. Wait. I post the URL.

Answer (score 2):

Simply use

```
isset($_GET['your_param'])
```

In your case maybe more like

```
if(isset($_GET['iln'])) {
    // .... set something
}
if(isset($_GET['sprache'])) {
    // .... set something else
}
```

Of course, that will work with URLs like `http://domain.com/script?iln=someValue`

Answer (score 1):

if your script is available at http://somehost.com/script.php
and you call it via http://somehost.com/script.php?param1=value1&param2=value2, you'll have `value1`,`value2` available at `$_GET` inside the script. If you want to know the name of the script called (script.php) or the host where the script is called (and many more), try `$_POST`. Is that what you need?

Comment: not sure, I think, I have my solution in another answer. Still thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
if ($_REQUEST['rvar_store']){
 ... set something
 }
```

Answer (score 1):

The use `import_request_variables()` is discouraged; in fact, it will be removed in PHP 5.4;  PHP will automatically copy request variables in their respective super globals such as `$_GET` (for variables on the query string) and `$_POST` (for posted content).

To test for the existence of `store=true` in the query string:

```
if (isset($_GET['store']) && 'true' == $_GET['store'])) {
    // store is given and contains 'true'
}
```